# Can someone give an explanation for this array length?

Tags: java, arrays, size

```
    String  inputList ="I dont understand this";
    String[]    temp = new String[1];       
    temp = inputList.split(" ");
    System.out.println(temp.length);
```

We can store only fixed set of elements in a java array.
But I declared the size of the array as one then tried to store four elements. I can see the size increased to 4. Why?  We can store only the fixed size of elements in the array. It doesn't grow its size. Then why I have the size as four instead of one?

Comment: No, you are not declaring the array as size one. You are just assigning the reference `temp` to point to an array of size one. Then you assign a reference to an array of size four to it. Your original array is never changed and is just garbage collected.

Comment: @pvg I prefer the expression "eligible for garbage collection", as there is no guarantee the old array is actually garbage collected.

Comment: @Mena sure. There's also no guarantee that the sun rises but it's reasonably likely and a sensible informal shortcut to pretend there is.

Comment: @pvg didn't want to sound pedantic, just accurate :)

Comment: @mena it's a totally reasonable point, although I'm tempted to say things like 'and the array is taken to a farm upstate' from now on.

Comment: @pvg "the array goes to arrays' heaven where indexes have no bounds"

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] temp = new String[1];
```

Here you created an array of 1 element and assigned it to the `temp` variable.

```
temp = inputList.split(" ");
```

Here you assigned to the `temp` variable a different array, created and returned by `inputList.split(" ")`, which can have a different number of elements (4 in your case).

The original 1 element array wasn't changed by that second assignment. However, after the second assignment, no variable is referring to the original array, so you can't access it anymore and it can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Because an assignment is **not** "fixing" a variable for all eternity.

A variable simply holds a **reference** to some object, in your case to an array.

First your variable *references* an array with one element. Then you change that so that the same variable is now *referencing* to **another** array (created by `split()`).

In case you want to *prevent* that from happening, you could use

```
final String[] temp = new String[1];
```

And now the *compiler* gives you an error when you try to *re-assign* another value to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is simple.

```
String  inputList ="I dont understand this";
String[]    temp = new String[1];       
temp = inputList.split(" ");//here you are simply changing the reference to 
                            //temp, now to store the result of split 
System.out.println(temp.length);
```

**temp** here is just a reference variable which was previously pointing to an array with only one element. But when the 3rd line of code executes then the **temp** start pointing to a new array of strings returned by the **split** function.

Answer (score -1):

because you are re-setting the "temp" variable, now it is inputList.split(" ");